# Календарь на текущий месяц

Tags: php

Оцените реализацию календаря:

```
<style>
table{
    tetx-align:center;
    width:200px
}

td{
    width:20px;
    height:30px
}
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>        
<?php
for($i=1; $i<date('t'); $i++)
{
    $time = mktime(date('h'), date('i'), date('s'), date('m'), 0+$i, date('Y'));
    $d = date('D', $time);

    if(date('j', $time) == 1)
    {
        if(date('w', $time) == 0)
            echo '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
        elseif(date('w', $time) == 6)
            echo '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
        elseif(date('w', $time) == 5)
            echo '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
        elseif(date('w', $time) == 4)
            echo '<td></td><td></td><td></td>';
        elseif(date('w', $time) == 3)
            echo '<td></td><td></td>';
        elseif(date('w', $time) == 2)
            echo '<td></td>';
    }

    if(date('D', $time) == 'Sun')
        echo '<td style="color:red;">'.date('j', $time).'</td></tr><tr>';
    else
        echo '<td>'.date('j', $time).'</td>';
}

?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: не нравится. явно не углядели в документации по date() символ для формата ``w``.

Comment: почему не нравится? разве код кривой? корректно отображает

Comment: Изменил код, использую date('w')

Comment: вам нужно один раз определить начало месяца, а вы проверяете каждый раз в цикле. сделайте цикл от 0 до date('w', первого числа месяца) для пустых ячеек, дальше просто цикл пока месяц не кончится. и не надо каждый раз вычислять день недели, в этом как раз "фишка" календаря что дни идут циклично, достаточно знать день недели первого числа месяца. код у вас сократится в разы.

Comment: не могу понять... можете написать, как это?

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в том, что вычисляем сразу день недели первого дня месяца и поехали:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<?php

$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), 1, date('Y'));
$firstday = (date('w', $time) + 6) % 7; //воскресенье сделаем 7-м днем, а не первым
$daycount = date('t', $time);
for ($i = 0; $i < $firstday; $i++) {
  echo '<td></td>';
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $daycount; $i++) {
  if (($firstday + $i) % 7 == 0) echo '<td style="color:red;">'.$i.'</td></tr>';
  else {
    if (($firstday + $i) % 7 == 1) echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
  }
}
if (($firstday + $firstday) % 7 != 0) {
  for ($i = ($daycount + $firstday + 6) % 7; $i < 7; $i++) {
    echo '<td></td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}

?>
</table>
```

как-то так.

ЗЫ можно все три цикла в один цикл объединить, но не стал делать ради читаемости.